# Why can't I extend an interface "generic method" and narrow its type to my inherited interface "class generic"?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I show an example of what I mean which, is easier. 
**Imagine the generic type C means Color type: So for
visual simplification assume C is C extends Color**

```
interface Screen {
   <C> Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);
}

interface MonochromeScreen<C> extends Screen{
       @Override
       Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);  
}
```

This would throw a name clash compilation error explaining that both have the same type erasure but are not overridable.

But I cannot understand why we could not simply allow overriding the signature as long as it is more restrictive. I mean, after all, the only difference is the scope of the generic type, in Screen is method-wide and in MonochromeScreen is class-wide.

It would not make sense to allow a child method to override as a method-scoped generic when its parent enforces coherence at class level, but I think it does otherwise: My parent interface could have 20 methods with unrelated generic types, but my child class would force them all to be the same as a non-incompatible extra specification/contract (which is what any extended interface does), After all, a monochrome sccreen is still an screen, as it can be painted with any color, I am just enforcing that color, whichever it is, to be it consistent accross the other functions of the child, Just narrowing the possibilities at class level, not method level.

Is there any fundamentally wrong assumption for considering the feature?

**EDIT: I accepted Sotirios Delimanolis answer for him spotted the right trouble very cleverly and I was not asking for a solution, but for those who want to know how to overcome the situation there is a trick explained in my own answered answer**

Comment: did you really mean to call one function `paint` and the other `render` ?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, thanks for spotting it! I was wondering what was more "graphical" (pun intended) for the example

Comment: What you are describing is probably one more of those limitations of the Java compiler justified as "feature is unlikely to be needed and it would unnecessarily complicate the compiler", though let's see if anyone comes up with some better explanation.

Comment: Well, I could see value on things like an executor which is both a CompletionService and an ExecutorService, for instance, to name an example (submit method would conflict exactly as in my example),

Comment: `For those staying on the Liskov principle and that, wouldn't be a violation anyway the fact that I can do this?` No, it wouldn't. There's nothing **userful** you can do with a `List<?>` that you couldn't do with an `ArrayList<String>`. So semantically (and LSP is a semantic principle) there is no violation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's where this breaks:

```
MonochromeScreen<Red> redScreen = ...;
Screen redScreenJustAScreen = redScreen;
Plane<Blue> bluePlane = null;
redScreenJustAScreen.<Blue>render(bluePlane);
```

If what you suggested worked at compile time, the snippet above would presumably have to fail at runtime with a `ClassCastException` because the object referenced by `redScreenJustAScreen` expects a `Plane<Red>` but received a `Plane<Blue>`.

Generics, used appropriately, are supposed to prevent the above from happening. If such overriding rules were allowed, generics would fail.

I don't know enough about your use case, but it doesn't seem like generics are really needed.

Comment: I took the freedom to edit the generic type values in accordance to its meaning declared in the question (color)

Comment: You really spotted the light. Thanks!. Still, I feel like this could be perfectly legal. When redScreen is used as a MonochromeScreen, only Red planes are allowed, when used as a super Screen, any color plane is allowed. You internally can deal with it, as a monochrome screen can deal with any color in the end. As long as it does not keep state. If he stores the plane in a var, and then we recast to the subtype and use a getter, then it would fail.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this is not allowed is that it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

```
interface Screen {
   <C> Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);
}
```

What this means is that you can call `render()` at any time with an arbitrary type as `C`.

You can do this for example:

```
Screen s = ...;
Background<Red> b1 = s.render(new Plane<Red>());
Background<Blue> b2 = s.render(new Plane<Blue>());
```

Now if we look at `MonochromeScreen`:

```
interface MonochromeScreen<C> extends Screen{
   Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);  
}
```

What this declaration says is: you must choose exactly one type as `C` when you create an instance of this object and you can only use that for the whole life of that object.

```
MonochromeScreen<Red> s = ...;
Background<Red>  b1 = s.render(new Plane<Red>());
Background<Blue> b2 = s.render(new Plane<Blue>()); // this won't compile because you declared that s only works with Red type.
```

Therefore it follows that `Screen s = new MonochromeScreen<Red>();` is not a valid cast, `MonochromeScreen` cannot be a subclass of `Screen`.

---

Okay, let's turn this around a bit. Let's assume that all colors are instances of a single `Color` class and not separate classes. What would our code look like then?

```
interface Plane {
    Color getColor();
}

interface Background {
    Color getColor();
}

interface Screen {
   Background render(Plane plane);
}
```

So far, so good. Now we define a monochrome screen:

```
class MonochromeScreen implements Screen {
    private final Color color; // this is the only colour we have
    public Background render(Plane plane) {
        if (!plane.getColor().equals(color))
           throw new IllegalArgumentException( "I can't render this colour.");
        return new Background() {...}; 
    }
}
```

This would compile fine and would have more or less the same semantics.

The question is: **would this be good code?** After all, you can still do this:

```
public void renderPrimaryPlanes(Screen s) { //this looks like a good method
    s.render(new Plane(Color.RED));
    s.render(new Plane(Color.GREEN));
    s.render(new Plane(Color.BLUE));
}

...
Screen s = new MonochromeScreen(Color.RED);
renderPrimaryPlanes(s); //this would throw an IAE
```

Well, no. That's definitely not what you'd expect from an innocent `renderPrimaryPlanes()` method. Things would break in unexpected ways. Why is that?

It's because despite it being formally valid and compileable, this code too breaks the LSP in exactly the same way the original did. The problem is not with the language but with the model: the entity you called `Screen` can do more things than the one called `MonochromeScreen`, therefore it can't be a superclass of it.

Comment: I took the freedom to edit the generic type values in accordance to its meaning declared in the question (color)

Comment: *"The reason this is not allowed is that it violates the Liskov substitution principle."* ...  I can't agree.  The compiler does not enforce the semantics of the LSP.  It is certainly possible to define a class hierarchy in Java that does not adhere to the tenets of the LSP.  In this case, the compiler objects to ambiguity created by type erasure, and not because it is trying to enforce the substitution principle.

Comment: @scottb What the compiler does or doesn't do is a separate matter, and in many ways just a distraction from the real problem. The compiler can't ensure complete code correctness, some things it can prevent, others it cannot. Regardless, this code would be fundamentally wrong even if the compiler couldn't detect it because it violates the LSP. That the compiler is able to tell you that the override isn't correct is just a bonus.

Comment: *"Regardless, this code would be fundamentally wrong even if the compiler couldn't detect it because it violates the LSP."* ... I contend that it is possible to have a class hierarchy that violates the LSP and which is still *correct*.  Violation of the LSP certainly has implications for code fragility and maintainability, but not necessarily for code correctness.  Therefore, in my view, it is not appropriate to assert that any code which violates LSP is "fundamentally wrong."

Comment: @scottb Any code that violates the LSP can be extended in completely valid ways to break. (I've just shown the way to do it for OPs scenario.) That's why it is fundamentally wrong, even if given a specific set of circumstances it may produce the correct behaviour.

Comment: @scottb To demonstrate the difference, take the following code: `foo.bar(null)`. Now if `foo` is `null`, this code is incorrect, right? But what if `bar()` would've thrown an NPE anyway because it doesn't accept a `null` parameter? Would that make the code correct? No, even though it would coincidentally produce the correct result.

Comment: @biziclop: I know what LSP is.  it's your semantics to which I object.  Does LSP affect maintainabiity and fragility?  I agree that it does.  Does LSP affect correctness?  No, not necessarily.  As proof of principle, consider the Java Platform Libraries: there are examples of class hierarchies that violate LSP ... and yet there are millions of lines of code in programs in Java that function properly.  LSP is similar to "Database Normalization".  You can have non-normalized databases that are correct, but you wouldn't necessarily want to be the one to maintain them.

Comment: @scottb Okay, let's leave it at that then, I don't want to get into a philosophical debate into the difference between "functioning properly" and "being correct".  The reason this specific construct isn't allowed however definitely **is** that it violates LSP in the way I described.

Comment: Look my own answer please, I found a way.  It's theoretically possible the inheritance case. with a bit of a trick,

Comment: @Whimusical Of course it is possible, I showed that in my answer too, but only by giving up compile-time type checking, therefore negating the whole point of using generics. But it would be still bad code that doesn't work correctly, it will produce the correct result only if the stars are right.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think your code is what you want, which is why you are getting errors.

I think this is what you want

```
public interface Screen<C> {
    Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);
}
```

and

```
public interface MonochromeScreen<C> extends Screen<C> {

  Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);
}
```

What you may be mistaken in thinking is that because `<C>` is both interfaces it is the same thing. It is not.

this

```
public interface MonochromeScreen<HI> extends Screen<HI> {

  Background<HI> render(Plane<HI> plane);
}
```

is exactly the same as the code above. C and HI are just names for the generic placeholders. by extending `Screen<C>` with `extends Screen<HI>` we tell java that C is the same placeHolder as HI so it will do it's magic.

In your code

```
<C> Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);
```

we have declared a brand new place holder that only has context in that method.
so we could write this code

```
MonochromeScreen<String> ms;
ms.render(new Plane<Banana>());

<C> Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);
```

is redefined as

```
Background<Banana> render(Plane<Banana> plane);
```

but

```
Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);
```

is redefined as

```
Background<String> render(Plane<String> plane);
```

which conflict and so java gives you an error.

Comment: Thanks !! But it is not a typo. Screen<C> has no sense as a normal screen can render multiple colors. So render must allow rendering a plane of any color. Monochrome screen, instead has only one type of color, and this is class-typed.

Comment: @Whimusical Then `MonochromeScreen` cannot be a descendant of `Screen`, as it trivially violates the Liskov substitution principle, which would require that anything you can do with `Screen` should be allowed for all its subclasses.

Comment: You still can do exactly everyhting. The difference is that you extend the contract by forcing that type to be shared among other methods. A MonoScreen can still render in any color type, it is an Screen. But whatever is that color, it must be the same everywhere. It all depends on interpreting the generic method in an interface as "force to allow multiple types in render  ", or "allow multiple types in the forced render". At the end, one is assuming the generic is meta-informative, instead of contract. But, when inheriting, erasures are the only thing that matters, not coherent.

Comment: The problem is that if you use the syntax input<?> for forcing any type, then you don't have the meta-generic to tell that return type must be the same, as long as you don't want to end up forcingthe scope of the generic at class level.

Comment: @Whimusical `But whatever is that color, it must be the same everywhere.` And since the method declaration in `Screen` says "you can pass in an arbitrary colour for any invocation of this method", that violates LSP. There is no other valid interpretation of `<C> Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane);`

Comment: That is not a closed interpretation. Your statement wouid apply faithfully to Background<?> render(Plane<?> plane); There is something else. What is actually saying most accurately is "the return type must be the same as the input type, whichever it is". Whether you infer it is also saying "and no one should ever restrict its use to a single unknown type" ot not seems orthogonal to me

Comment: @Whimusical It might seem orthogonal to you, but that is the key semantic meaning of an instance method with its own type parameter. That the input is the same as the output is neither here nor there. you could define your method to return `void` and you'd still be in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: That is the only way I found to solve the case and pass the overriding of the method (If the design pattern has a name, I'd appreciate to know ir! It's in the end the way to extend an interface with generic methods to make it class-generic. And still you can type it with the parent type (aka Color) to use it as the raw general type old interface.):

**Screen.java**

```
public interface Screen {
    public interface Color {}
    public class Red  implements Color {}
    public class Blue implements Color {}

    static Screen getScreen(){
        return new Screen(){};
    }
    default <C extends Color> Background<C> render(Plane<C> plane){
        return new Background<C>(plane.getColor());
    }
}
```

**MonochromeScreen.java**

```
interface MonochromeScreen<C extends Color> extends Screen{

    static <C extends Color> MonochromeScreen<C> getScreen(final Class<C> colorClass){
        return new MonochromeScreen<C>(){
            @Override public Class<C> getColor() { return colorClass; };
        };
    }

    public Class<C> getColor();

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    default Background<C> render(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Plane plane){
        try{
            C planeColor = (C) this.getColor().cast(plane.getColor());
            return new Background<C>(planeColor);
        } catch (ClassCastException e){
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Current screen implementation is based in mono color '" 
                                                   + this.getColor().getSimpleName() + "' but was asked to render a '"
                                                   + plane.getColor().getClass().getSimpleName() + "' colored plane" );
        }
    }
}
```

**Plane.java**

```
public class Plane<C extends Color> {   
    private final C color;
    public Plane(C color) {this.color = color;}
    public C getColor()   {return this.color;}
}
```

**Background.java**

```
public class Background<C extends Color> {  
    private final C color;
    public Background(C color) {this.color = color;}
    public C getColor()        {return this.color;}
}
```

**MainTest.java**

```
public class MainTest<C> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Plane<Red> redPlane   = new Plane<>(new Red());
        Plane<Blue> bluePlane = new Plane<>(new Blue());

        Screen coloredScreen = Screen.getScreen();
        MonochromeScreen<Red> redMonoScreen = MonochromeScreen.getScreen(Red.class);
        MonochromeScreen<Color> xMonoScreen = MonochromeScreen.getScreen(Color.class);

        Screen redScreenAsScreen = (Screen) redMonoScreen;

        coloredScreen.render(redPlane);
        coloredScreen.render(bluePlane);
        redMonoScreen.render(redPlane);
        //redMonoScreen.render(bluePlane); --> This throws UnsupportedOperationException*
        redScreenAsScreen.render(redPlane);
        //redScreenAsScreen.render(bluePlane); --> This throws UnsupportedOperationException*
        xMonoScreen.render(new Plane<>(new Color(){})); //--> And still I can define a Monochrome screen as of type Color so  
        System.out.println("Test Finished!");           //still would have a wildcard to make it work as a raw screen (not useful 
                                                        //in my physical model but it is in other abstract models where this problem arises

    } 
}
```

- Exception thrown when adding blue plane in redScreen:

  > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Current screen implementation
  >   is based in mono color 'Red' but was asked to render a 'Blue' colored
  >   plane

Comment: So what's the point of generics here then, given that no compile-time type checking is happening?

Comment: Render return type is still compliant, though not used in the main test